# Can wine be made from raisins?

Tags: wine, brewing, ingredients, nutrition

What wine is made from raisins not grapes?  What would be different in nutrients in wine made raisins vs grapes? How would the process differ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways to make wine from raisins.

1. Soak the raisins in water and boil and then macerate, ferment and separate the solids from the wine and age. You can make something close to wine. Most raisin grapes are Thompson Seedless grapes which are white grapes. It might be cloudy if you don't use pectic enzymes. [Here is a recipe](http://winemaking.jackkeller.net/reques97.asp)
2. [The more traditional method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straw_wine) is to raisin wine grapes either on the vine or store them inside to dry them out. Some call it "Straw Wine" but there are numerous names for this method. Basically the same principle as late harvest wine except even drier grapes. Sometimes added to regular wine sometimes pressed with super high brix levels, almost like syrup.

Comment: Might be nice to mention Amarone wine which is made using dried grapes as part of this answer. Amarone is really good wine if expensive. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amarone

Comment: Amarone has a big mention in the 2nd wikipedia article I mentioned...